# Rails: How to render a layout around a collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, code-cleanup

Rails supports `:layout` option when rendering collection partials, but the layout applies to the every element in the list.

Is there a way to add a layout around the whole collection?

### Details

Let's say I have a collection `@promoted_stories`. I want to render some HTML around the rendered collection, but only if `@promoted_stories` is not empty. What I want can be achieved in this way:

```
<% if @prometed_stories.present? %>
<div class="promoted-stories>
  <%= render @promoted_stories %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Can I do the same and avoid the `if`? I'm a fan of logic-less layouts, so I would like to avoid as much branching in my views if possible. I'd prefer if something like this was possible:

```
# View:
<%= render collection: @promoted_stories, collection_layout: 'promoted_stories' %>

# _promoted_stories.html.erb
<div class="promoted-stories">
  <%= yield %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While not as elegant as imagined solution, this should achieve similar results:

```
# Helper
def render_collection_template(template, collection)
  render template: "layouts/#{template}", locals: { collection: collection } if collection.present?
end

# View
<%= render_collection_template 'promoted_stories', @promoted_stories %>

# Template
<div class="promoted-stories">
  <%= render collection %>
</div>
```

There is now a [pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/17524) for rails implementing collection layout for collection render.

Comment: Thanks! The first one is closest to what I wanted to achieve. The second and the third still introduce the noise in the view that I wanted to get rid of in the first place.